# What is the proper use case for modules?

Tags: marionette

I currently have a Backbone.js site that is functioning properly. However, this site is starting to get quite large and turning into Backbone Spaghetti really quick.

To address this I think Marionette.js is the way to go and I started looking at it last week and attempting to come up with a proof of concept using it. My initial thinking was that each set of routes (i.e. servers & servers/:id) of the site should be their own module. For example, the list of Servers and then when you open up a server, the form and related lists would all be one module and what is displayed depends on the route (servers or server/:id). Then when you navigate to some other route, I would stop that module, reset the content region and start up a different one.

So my question is this... am I using modules as they were intended? Or, should a module be the broader sense of the word, meaning individual "mini" apps (i.e. chat widget, notifications widget, etc), stuff that isn't "required" for the overall purpose of the site to keep on functioning regardless of that module's state (started or stopped)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are intended to be mini apps like you mentioned. An approach that is even more modern is organizing your code with RequireJS. It will force you to fit your code in a modular structure.

Routes that belongs together (/admin/users , /admin/users/2/view , /admin/users/2/edit, /admin/users/new, etc) you should group them in a Marionette controller.

After you're familiarized with Marionette, you'll likely find a way to use the recently launched feature: Behaviors. They promote reuse of code and make your views even more slim.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So I was approaching this the wrong way. As for Behaviors, yes, I have started looking at them and must say they're freakin cool. I'm also using require.js and the old site is also. But I had a few views that were hundreds of lines long and when I added some feature it would break something else. So something had to change to make this easier to maintain.